# Graphics.X11.Xlib Haskell

Tags: haskell, x11, xlib

I'm trying to get the `import Graphics.X11.Xlib` running from my GHC, but  I get

> Could not find module ‘Graphics.X11.Xlib’

How do you normally deal with this kind of issue, when you don't know where a module is located, or whether it is there at all?

Cabal X11 installed

Comment: You say "Cabal X11 installed". What does that mean, exactly? (What command did you run to install X11? Are you using a sandbox? Are you using new-*?) What does `ghc-pkg list X11` say?

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/8.2.2-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-8.2.2/package.conf.d
    (no packages)
/Users/ivankretov/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-8.2.2/package.conf.d
    (no packages)
I'm using a Mac btw

Comment: The command was cabal install x11

Comment: What was the output when you ran `cabal install x11`? I suspect it did not succeed, and printed error messages that you will need to diagnose.

Comment: It actually did work, it went all the way through an installation list. Shame I did not save it

Comment: It is not harmful to run it again. Consider doing so and including the output in a code block in your question.

Comment: I'm very new to stackoverflow, should I ask a new question, or is there a way to continue this thread? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Click "edit" under your question to include additional information.